# Script at the bottom?

Tags: knockout.js

I include my viewmodel script at the bottom of the page and have a problem. The matter is until `applyBindings` is called (which is also at the bottom) user can see the **not binded** page for a second where naked template is displayed. One of the solutions is to place scripts at the top and wrap `applyBindings` in `$()` or "document ready". But I really refuse to accept there is no way to solve the problem and keep scripts at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always use something like this:

```
<div data-bind="visible:true" style="display:none">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the elements in question with CSS and display them after `applyBindings`

**CSS**

```
.hide-while-loading { display: none }
```

**JS**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-while-loading ');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    // remove class:
    elements[i].className = elements[i].className.replace('/\bhide-while-loading\b/','');
}
```

Actually the code removes the `hide-while-loading` class instead of just making the elements visible, so that elements that *should* be hidden, stay hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css binding to toggle visibility of the unbound elements.

Likely on a containing element, do something like this:

```
<div data-binding="css: { notready: !isReady()}" class="notready">
  Other children with bindings
</div>
```

Add a CSS class:

```
.notready { display : none; }
```

Then, add a new observable to your view model:

```
isReady : ko.observable(true)
```

The code toggles/removes the `notready` CSS class when `isReady` evaluates to `true`.